# Elasticsearch - searching for a record which is part of a value in array

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to build a query in elasticsearch 5.1, for example - give me all the books that the author is in a list of predefined authors. when using single author it is working , but when passing an array - I am getting no result

```
let query = JSON.stringify({
        "size": 10000,
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [{
                        "term": {
                            "recordtype": "Book"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "recordLocation": "library"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "filter": {
                    "term": {
                        "author": authors
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

where authors are`let authors = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`

what do I miss?

Comment: Replace term query with terms query as shown below `"term": {
                        "author": authors
                    }` with `"terms": {
                        "author": ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
                    }`

Comment: thanks - it solved it

Comment: Glad! It helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Terms Query` when looking for multiple keywords.

Replace your filter query as shown below:

```
"filter": {
     "terms": {
       "author":["a", "b, "c"]
      }
 }
```